# Nvidia card 640M can't be detected

Tags: nvidia, resolution, intel, vga, detect

I am new in Ubuntu. I have a Acer v3-571g with Nvidia 640M and Intel HD 4000. I installed Ubuntu and Nvidia driver but I can't choose resolution 640x480. I tried reinstalling the driver, configured `xorg` but no help. I reinstalled Ubuntu and use command to see my graphic cards. I saw bad result, Ubuntu can't detect model my Nvidia.

How I can fix this?

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:b3000000-b33fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff iopor
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu uses the nouveau driver. I have the same issue and due to my /var/log/Xorg.0.log0 this driver seems not yet to be ready to drive 640M (which is very new). I tried to upgrade to the latest nouveau driver manually with no success. For now the only way to go for you is to use the proprietary Nvidia driver:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia